# How to upgrade a Debian 9 to Debian 9.5?

Tags: debian

I'm looking to upgrade a Debian machine from `9` to `9.5`.
How can I upgrade to a specific version? Is that even possible?

Comment: To adjust the linked answer to your circumstances, run `wget -q -O - https://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/cdimage/archive/9.5.0/amd64/jigdo-bd/debian-9.5.0-amd64-BD-1.jigdo | gunzip | awk -F= '/snapshot.debian.org/ {print $2}'` — this gives `http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20180715T102429Z/`.

Answer (score 0):

From the debian 9.5 release notes:

> Please note that the point release does not constitute a new version
> of Debian 9 but only updates some of the packages included. There is
> no need to throw away old "stretch" media. After installation,
> packages can be upgraded to the current versions using an up-to-date
> Debian mirror.
> New installation images will be available soon at the regular
> locations.
>
> Upgrading an existing installation to this revision can be achieved by
> pointing the package management system at one of Debian's many HTTP
> mirrors. A comprehensive list of mirrors is available at:
>
> https://www.debian.org/mirror/list

The 9.5 release only adds updated packages to the distributed installation media.

You can simply upgrade your running system by running `apt update && apt upgrade -y`

Comment: This would upgrade to 9.13, not 9.5. (I do reckon it’s best to just upgrade to the latest, but that’s not what the question is asking.)